# After button submit, refresh page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wordpress version 4.9.8` and `PHP 7.1.8`.

Below you can see, that I have added a button to my post. This button inserts content into `the_content` field of a post. After submitting the button I would like to refresh the single post page and show the content.

Find below my code for the button:

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_my_media_button', 99);
function add_my_media_button()
{

    $post = $GLOBALS['post_ID'];
    echo "<a href='#' id='insert-my-media' data-post-id='{$post}' class='button'>Own content</a>";

}

add_action('wp_ajax_updateContent', 'updateContent');
function updateContent()
{

    $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);

    try {
        $sp = new SinglePostContent();
        $sp->main($post_id);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'my_media_button_script');

function my_media_button_script()
{

    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#insert-my-media').click(function () {
                var post_id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
                var data = {
                    'action': 'updateContent',
                    'post_id': post_id
                };
                // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                    console.log("test12")
                    console.log(response);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php
}
```

Any suggestions how to refresh the page and show the content.

Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: What do you mean "refresh", you mean reload the page?  `location.reload(true);` in the callback for the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this :

```
[...]
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
  console.log("test12")
  console.log(response);
  window.location.reload();
});
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

in callback function, reload the page:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    console.log("test12")
    console.log(response);
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
           jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                console.log("test12")
                console.log(response);
                location.reload(true);
            });
```

use `ture` in reload to make a hard refresh reload from the server.
or you can return the updated post content and use `html()` to replace it without a refresh.